# Proguard fails with RetroLambda and custom build type

Tags: android

I'm trying make use of Lambda expressions in my Instrumentation tests in my Android app, but they fail with the following error each time I build:

```
:myapp:proguardItestAndroidTest
Warning:com.myapp.OfflineTests: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:com.myapp.OfflineTests: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
```

Now these errors are well known, and usually fixable with the following line in `proguard.txt`:

`-dontwarn java.lang.invoke.*`

..and it does in the release and debug build, but not the custom build type "itest" I've made. Anyone got any explanation for that? I am indeed specifying the same proguard rule files for the itest build as for the release:

```
    itest { // Needed because I-tests needs special permissions (turn on/off wifi)
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.txt', '../lib/proguard-common.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        debuggable true
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }
```

edit: I know that the file is correctly loaded becuase the task `proguardItest` runs successfully, but fails if I empty the file. It is the task  `proguardItestAndroidTest` that fails